# Repeat test in pytest but regard all repetitions together as one test only

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, repeat

I want to repeat a test and it should fail if one of those repetitions fails. So basically:

```
def test_example():
    for _ in range(5):
        assert random.randint(0, 1)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Since I'd have to modify the test function `test_example` itself for this (insert the `for` loop), I'd rather just have a decorator to do the same.

However, if I use

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("reps", range(5))
def test_example(reps):
    assert random.randint(0, 1)
```

or

```
@pytest.mark.repeat(5)
def test_example():
    assert random.randint(0, 1)
```

I get a total of 5 tests - but I want 1 test result for all 5 tests together.

Comment: Why not just put a loop in the test, then?

Comment: You can define your own test running protocol where you execute the underlying test function n times, but the benefit of it is questionable IMO. Why do you want to repeat the tests, exactly? If you want to find and/or rerun flaky tests, `pytest` already has plugins supporting that, e.g. [`flaky`](https://pypi.org/project/flaky/) or [`pytest-flakefinder`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-flakefinder/).

Comment: Ah, take a look at [`hypothesis`](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis) designed for random but reproducible test data generation. It's compatible with `pytest` and has the feature you're looking for - a single test is executed n times with different inputs, but listed once in report.

Comment: Do you really need some stochastic testing, or do you repeat the test just because you are not able to control the random input for your software unit?